# Скрыть Private Key в клиенте WireGuard

Tags: wireguard

Клиенты Windows. Хочу реализовать впн на базе wireguard - firezone.dev, но меня беспокоит возможность потери конфига пользователем, так как сам конфиг ничем не защищен. Думаю PrivateKey отправлять отдельно, но тогда стоит вопрос - можно ли PrivateKey скрыть в клиенте WireGuard? мало ли кто-нибудь скопирует конфиг или возможно есть клиенты Wireguard c паролем? Подскажите, кто как решал данную пробему.

Comment: Не очень понятно в чём собственно вопрос. Что вы имеете в виду под словом «потери» и почему вы считаете это проблемой?

Comment: Я имею ввиду что конфиг пользователя может быть дискредитирован, например, если конфиг будет на флешке и она будет утеряна, данный конфиг может найти какое-нибудь сторонее лицо или пользователь случайно оставит конфиг где-нибудь. WireGuard к сожалению не имеет фунционала дополнительной аутентификации по паролю как тот же openvpn.

Comment: Если пользователь настолько некомпетентен, то он и пароль на ту же самую флешку запишет. По-моему беспокоиться о таких вещах нет практического смысла